# Central Administration Application pool Stopping

Tags: iis

My SharePoint 2010 Central administration  Application pool in IIS7 only works with my domain Administartor account. The Service Account I created crashed the application pool

Answer (score 0):

I hope you had configured your service account by following the below steps.

Launch Central Admin ,Go to Security and under General Security, click Configure Service Accounts.
Select the application pool from the components drop-down listbox

- Select the managed account that you want to use as the identity for
  this application pool, or register a new managed account in
  SharePoint 2010, using the Register a new managed account link.
- Click the OK button.
- You’ll be warned that this action requires an IIS reset on all
  servers, click OK.
- Perform a iisreset /noforce on all WFE servers in the farm.